# how to access typescript class member from Javascript callback in one of class local method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, callback

i have the folloing code:

```
export class AuthService {
  token: string;
  refreshToken: string;
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  signinUser(username: string, password: string) {
      const user = new mylib.User(username, password);
      user.requestSessionToken(true, {
        onOk: function (result) {
          let tokenMap: any;
          tokenMap = result;
          this.token = tokenMap.sessionToken;
          this.refreshToken = tokenMap.refreshToken;
          mylib.Datastore.configureWithSessionToken(this.token);
          this.router.navigate(['/signup']);
        },
        onError: function (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      });
      console.log(this.token);
      console.log('signinUser Called!');
  }
}
```

`mylib` is Javascript library and this is not pointing to my object so `this.token` is not woking
how can i access my class fields in Javascript block?

Comment: I think you will want to call `user.token`.  `this` refers to the function `signinUser` since you are calling it outside of the object literal. Also, it appears that `user.requestSessionToken` is async, so you may need to use a callback or promise to wait until the function is finished before accessing `this.token`.

Comment: `token` is local member in `AuthService` class not in `user`

Comment: Please refer this doc - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow function is the answer.

```
export class AuthService {
  token: string;
  refreshToken: string;
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  signinUser(username: string, password: string) {
      const user = new mylib.User(username, password);
      user.requestSessionToken(true, {
        onOk: (result) => {
          let tokenMap: any;
          tokenMap = result;
          this.token = tokenMap.sessionToken;
          this.refreshToken = tokenMap.refreshToken;
          mylib.Datastore.configureWithSessionToken(this.token);
          this.router.navigate(['/signup']);
        },
        onError: (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        }
      });
      console.log(this.token);
      console.log('signinUser Called!');
  }
}
```

alternatively (old-school), you can use `bind()`: `(function (result) { ... }).bind(this)`

The reason is in the `onOK` callback, this is probably the `user` instance, not your class.

Always be careful on what is `this` when you are dealing with callbacks.